# Is that possible to count GUI refresh count? Measuring GUI responsiveness

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, responsiveness

I am developing a WPF application and currently writing an article about it. I am at the experiments phase. I need to write responsiveness of GUI. However is that statistically possible to count how many times GUI is refreshed in certain time? When there is no lag full responsive i am updating with 0.5 second interval however there is being lag and it get updated with a delay. It is like half time frozen.

Can i measure this somehow ?

c# .net 4.5.2 WPF application

Comment: Take a look at Perforator from the [WPF Performance Suite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx). It allows you to measure the application's frame rate.

Comment: @Clemens can you link me where do i install Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit for windows 8.1 ?

Comment: @clemens 
 
ok i found and installed for .net 4.0 however it does not record fps anywhere :( so i am not able to calculate average FPS

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WPF Performance Suite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa969767) to get framerate and various other stats regarding gui. Check the Perforator section on details about gui stats.

Comment: ty for answer i am going to try. does this tool have logging like per minute? so i can have statistics. or can i call with like a reference and check framerate myself from application not from eyes ? i mean not from the WPF Performance Suite

Comment: can you link me where do i install Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit for windows 8.1 ?

Comment: ok i found and installed for .net 4.0 however it does not record fps anywhere :( so i am not able to calculate average FPS

Comment: Check the section titled "Perforator Graphs" on the MSDN link. That section has info is displayed as part of data.

Comment: yes however it does not have any logging so it is only visual. I need to record each second FPS on a file like a text file.